# issue of my php function inside my jquery code

Tags: php, jquery, function, integer

I Want to execute a php function inside the jquery function .html(). The php function takes 2 integers as parameter.

This code works

```
$(function() {
    var myVar = 1;
    $('#myDiv').html('<? echo my_function('+myVar+','+1+'); ?>');   
});
```

and this one doesn't:

```
$(function() {
    var myVar = 1;
    $('#myDiv').html('<? echo my_function('+myVar+','+myVar+'); ?>');   
});
```

I don't have a php error, but nothing happens

Comment: I highly doubt that the first code works either. JavaScript is executed on the client, PHP on the server. There is no way the server can use the `myVar` value in PHP.

Comment: What the error message? Also see [so-hints](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints)

Comment: @GeraldSchneider the first one does work, I assure you. So your point is I should use AJAX right?

Comment: @silentboy there is no error message, just nothing

Comment: @GradislavaBikkulova it may be possible to say more if you post your `my_function()` code.

Comment: @GradislavaBikkulova You can't just run PHP functions whenever you want. You need to do an AJAX call.

Comment: If you need AJAX or not depends on what you actually want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried it. So, what happens is this: The PHP parser only cares what's inside the `<? ?>`tags, nothing else. So it sees this:

```
echo my_function('+myVar+','+1+');
```

The function is called with two Parameters, both strings: `+myVar+` and `+1+`. You can check that by putting this in your function:

```
function my_function() {
    $argv = func_get_args();
    var_dump($argv);
}
```

It will output this:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "+myVar+"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "+1+"
}
```

After the PHP generated file is served the client sees this:

```
$(function() {
    var myVar = 1;
    $('#myDiv').html('The output of your my_function()');   
});
```

Your JavaScript variable now isn't used anymore.

If you want to print content with a already known ID you can either define the variable in PHP or use a `$_GET` or `$_POST` variable to set it in PHP.

If you want to use a dynamic value you will need an AJAX call to another file (where you will have to do what I suggested above).

Mixing PHP and JavaScript like you did is just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

write a `file.php`

```
<?php
my_function(myvar,1);
?>
```

and in html page use

```
$('#mydiv').load('file.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a wrong method,
   You cant use this method,
   var myvar; is a javascript variable,That will only available in your browser.But      my_function() executed in web server;You can put a php variable in javascript,But not possible to use a javascript variable as argument in php function.make myvar as a php variable,if possible then put it into your function.Or you can use ajax to pass a javascript variable to php function.

Put your function into a php file,Then

```
     $('#mydiv').load('file.php?myvar='+myvar);
```

is possible,You can get the value in $_GET['myvar']